# Symfony2 Application on CentOS with php_apc enabled is slow

Tags: php, apache, symfony, apc, vps

I have a VPS with the following configuration:

- 512 Mb
- 2x CPU
- CentOS is the OS and it is running the typical LAMP stack (Apache, MySQL and PHP 5.3).
- php_apc enabled.
  -The cache folders are writable.

The symfony2 application is slow **until it's loaded**.

The initial connection with the server is about 3-10 seconds but once the symfony2 application is loaded it's running pretty OK.

Another problem is that when registering an account I access the SMTP server using swift mailer and it takes about 20 seconds before the registration page has been succesfully processed.

I have other software running on the server also (Fork CMS, CodeIgniter applications, etc..) and they are running much faster.

Both the production as the development configuration have this slow loading problem.

Other measures I took:

- Using mod_deflate and the server tested succesfully for using Gzip compression when serving the webpages.

Comment: I suggest you install xdebug and see which function slows down the site. Symfony 2 works well on my 1xCPU Ubuntu typical LAMP stack.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BlackFire to find the problem. Enabling APC only won't help. You need to add Doctrine Queries and Meta to APC cache, this has huge impact on performance. Blackfire will tell you if there is a problem also with routing. Maybe you need to enable also APC in front controller to optimize loading classes.

Answer (score -3):

I have this problem too, there are some way for speeding up the framework like using Apc, HTTP cache and some caching configuration for doctrine, I almost try all of them but I think the real problem is symfony2!! It's a big framework with a lot of tools so for initial time it takes a long time for reading these resource, so the best way that I found is using other framework like codeigniter it's so fast and lovely.

Comment: I think you just are not enough expirienced to use that kind of frameworks. -1 for not a real answer.

Comment: @user2204048 No, it's not symfony2 as a framework itself. It's probably a configuration or cache leverage that I have yet to discover. Symfony2 is perfectly suitable for large scale web applications.

Comment: Yes I'm agree that "symfony2 is perfectly suitable for large scale web applications." But I don't think that anyone run a large scale application on a server like that you mentioned!!